# SharePoint Blog Template Master Page Branding

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

This may be a simple question, but I am having a problem with it.

I have multiple publishing SharePoint sites & sub-sites with a customized master page.  I now have a sub-site based off the Blog site template. The custom master page is not being applied to it.  I checked to make sure the site's master page setting it pointing to the custom master page.

Do Blog Site Templates handle master pages differently?  If so, how do I brand these blog pages?  Do I have to handle them individually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I ended up just using SharePoint Designer to edit the masterpage for the Blog site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the blog sites use a different masterpage. You will have to go into the blog site using SharePoint designer and create a custom master page in the gallery.

I **heartily** recommend using the [CKS:EBE](http://cks.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5134) if you'll be using blogs on SharePoint. It has a multitude of improvements over the out of the box blog template including theming, trackbacks, spam protection and many others. Give it a shot!